# alternate to upload image or not

Tags: php, forms, image-uploading

I am new in stackoverflow and in PHP too, so I want to describe my problem first. Sorry if I have bad grammar, I am not native though.

I make a form that let user post (to database) with or without an image, this the code

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345!@#', 'pklapps') or die("Couldnt connect to the server");
//public info dari admin
if (isset($_POST["title"]) && isset($_POST["content"]) && isset($_POST["category"])) {

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $desc = $_POST['content'];
    $lat = $_POST['latitude'];
    $long = $_POST['longitude'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $image = $_POST['userfile'];

    if (!isset($_FILES['userfile'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO public_info (title, content, category) VALUES ('$title','$desc','$category')"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        if ($result) {
            header('Location: post.php?success');
        } else {
            header('Location: post.php?error');
        }
    } else {
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $target = "uploads/";
        $fileTarget = $target.$fileName; 
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);
        /*
        *   If file was successfully uploaded in the destination folder
        */
        if ($result) { 
            header('Location: post.php?success'); 
            $query = "INSERT INTO public_info (title, content, category, imagePath) VALUES ('$title','$desc','$category', '$fileTarget')";
            $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link)); 
        } else { 
            header('Location: post.php?errimg'); 
        }

        mysqli_close($link);
    }
}
```

and the form goes normal when i attach the image or file but it goes to `header('Location: post.php?errimg');` when i not attach the image. Please help me with this, thank you.

Comment: Try `file_exists($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: why set the header before trying to insert into the db?

Comment: i am sorry, a didn't understand what do you mean @RamRaider

Comment: In your code you set a header before the sql query ( `header('Location: post.php?success'); ` ) ~ this should be AFTER the sql query

Comment: okay i see that, thanks a lot @RamRaider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your if condition from `!isset($_FILES['userfile'])` to `empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])`

```
    //if (!isset($_POST[]))
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $desc = $_POST['content'];
    $lat = $_POST['latitude'];
    $long = $_POST['longitude'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $image = $_POST['userfile'];

    if(empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO public_info (title, content, category) VALUES ('$title','$desc','$category')"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        if ($result) {
            header('Location: post.php?success');
        }

        else {
            header('Location: post.php?error');
        }
    }
    else {
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $target = "uploads/";
        $fileTarget = $target.$fileName; 
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);
        /*
        *   If file was successfully uploaded in the destination folder
        */
        if($result) { 
            header('Location: post.php?success'); 
            $query = "INSERT INTO public_info (title, content, category, imagePath) VALUES ('$title','$desc','$category', '$fileTarget')";
            $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link)); 
            }
        else { 
            header('Location: post.php?errimg'); 
            }
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    // $query = "INSERT INTO public_info (title, content, category) VALUES ('$title','$desc','$category')";   
}       ?>
```

Comment: Without explanation of any changes made or points regarding the original problem this is not very helpful